# Enum design with lots of fields

Tags: java, enums

I want to implement a EAN128 barcode parser. In short, EAN128 barcode is built by one or more fields, each one composed by a string identifier and a value. There is a hundred different identifiers and each value has fix or variable length (numeric or alphanumeric) depends on the identifier. Variable length value ends with special char named FNC1.
I want get all identifiers and its value from a barcode.
My design is based in an enumeration with one field for each code identifier.

```
public enum IDENT_EAN128 {
  // Identifier 8003 that has a value composed by 14 numeric chars and 1 to 20 alphanumeric chars
  IDENT_8003 ("8003", FixedParser(14, NUMERIC), VariableParser(20, ALPHANUMERIC)),
  IDENT_00   ("00", FixedParser(18, NUMERIC)),

  .... // hundred identifiers

  private IDENT_EAN128 (String code, Parser... parsers ) {
     ...
  }

  public static IDENT_EAN128 search (String code) {
    // loop IDENT_EAN128.values() to search code identifier
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void test () {
    String id1 = "8003";
    String field1 = "12345678901234";
    String field2 = "12345" + FNC1;

    String id2 = "00";
    String field3 = "123456789012345678";

    String barcode = id1 + field1 + field2 + id2 + field3;
    for (int posBarcode; posBarcode < barcode.length(); posBarcode++) { // loop chars of barcode
      char[] buffer ...
      IDENT_EAN128 idEAN = IDENT_EAN128.search(buffer)
      if (idEAN != null) {
        // loop Parsers for get identifier value
        // move posBarcode to the first barcode position of next identifier
      }
      ....
    }
  }
}
```

Parsers return identifier value, validate its length and that the value has the correct char type (numeric or alphanumeric).
The problem with this design is that when is called first time, it creates hundreds of new objects (each identifier and its parsers). Most times barcode only have 3 or 4 identifiers. So, I think it's a wate of time and memory. I have search about "lazy inizialitation" design for parsers, but I haven't found something that correspond with my problem. Is there a better design? or my concern is for nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can keep the enum approach. But make use of the enum Singleton feature. 
With that I mean you just have and INSTANCE enum value. Inside your enum you keep a hashmap with the code as key. Since your method uses the code as an input. See this:

```
public enum IDENT_EAN128_CACHE {

  INSTANCE;

  private static final Map<String, ParserStore> storage = new HashMap<>();

  public synchronized IDENT_EAN128 search (String code) {

    // If the code is already in the map return the needed values 

    // Else lazy initialize the hashmap entries if the requested entry is not contained and return it.

    return 'the value you should return';

    }

}
```

You are then able to access the functions like this:

```
IDENT_EAN128.INSTANCE.search("some code");
```

**Edit**:

With this design you cannot keep the IDENT_EAN128 as an Enum if you want to lazy initialize it. It should be an object initialized by the "enum cache" I provided the code for.

**Edit 2**: The modifications of the code suggested by Mike Strobel in the comments.

Comment: So where do the values in the `storage` map actually get read and returned?  Does the `search` method only return `INSTANCE`?

Comment: Using a Map for store Parser object seems a good idea, I only had two object instances of Parser objects. But is it thread safe? And as matt says, I don't see either how get the identifier from search method.

Comment: Please see the edit of my post. I clarified the logic inside the search function. So you return what you need if the code is contained in the map, and you initialize it otherwise. For the thread safety a lock in now protecting the access to the hashmap.

Comment: I'd mark the map field as `static final` and lock with a `synchronized` block (the `ReentrantLock` doesn't add any value here), but otherwise, looks good.

Comment: I am confused, are you keeping IDENT_EAN128 as an `enum`?  If not, then you should remove the `enum` keyword from its definition.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are creating a new enum called `IDENT_EAN128_CACHE`,  in addition to `IDENT_EAN128`.  In that case, why bother to make `IDENT_EAN128_CACHE` an enum?  Why not just make it a class?

Comment: I could make it a class. I just used an enum to implement the singleton behavior. An so create an easy to access cache.

Comment: I just don't understand at all your solution. I need to know that 8003 code have a 14 numeric fix parser and 20 alphanumeric variable parser. How can I build a lazy inizialitation? Enum structure allows me easily to "know" parsers thanks to constructor. If I build it without an enum, will I need hundred different classes (one for each identifier)?

Comment: To implement singleton behavior, it might be clearer to just have a class with a static member that is an object of that class.  (Similar to what you have here, but a class instead.)  Then to enforce the singleton behavior, you can make the constructor private.  It just seems to be a misuse of enums to have an enum with only one value (since it is not really enumerating anything).

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, your design is good, although I would use a statically-built map to do your search rather than looping over `values()`.  I would not worry about the extra memory or CPU cycles involved with creating a couple hundred extra objects.  They are only created once per JVM, so no big deal unless the objects are mammoth, or if you are running on a 286 from 1990.  Clear design is more important.  Note that I am also assuming `VariableParser` and `FixedParser` are classes, and inserted the `new` keyword in front of them to call the constructors.

You could populate the `codeMap` lazily if you want, but that won't buy you much.   Since all of the objects are already created, you would just be saving a tiny bit of initialization in creating Map entries.

```
public enum IDENT_EAN128 {
    // Identifier 8003 that has a value composed by 14 numeric chars and 1 to 20 alphanumeric chars
    IDENT_8003 ("8003", new FixedParser(14, NUMERIC), new VariableParser(20, ALPHANUMERIC)),
    IDENT_00   ("00", new FixedParser(18, NUMERIC));
    // ... hundred identifiers

    private static final HashMap<String, IDENT_EAN128> codeMap = new HashMap<String, IDENT_EAN128> ();
    static {
        for(IDENT_EAN128 ident: IDENT_EAN128.values()) {
            codeMap.put(ident.getCode(), ident);
        }
    }

    private String code;

    private IDENT_EAN128 (String code, Parser... parsers ) {
        this.code = code;
        // do something with parsers as well...
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static IDENT_EAN128 search (String code) {
        return codeMap.get(code);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. After consider them I have decided to keep Enumeration design but adding HashMap Matt suggestion and a lazy inizialitation for parsers in each identifier. So, code looks like this:

```
public enum IDENT_EAN128 {
  // Identifier 8003 that has a value composed by 14 numeric chars and 1 to 20 alphanumeric chars
  IDENT_8003 ("8003") {
    @Override public Parser[] getParsers () {
      return new Parser[]{new FixedParser(14, NUMERIC), new VariableParser(20, ALPHANUMERIC)};
    }
  },

  .... // hundred identifiers

  private static final HashMap<String, IDENT_EAN128> codeMap = new HashMap<String, IDENT_EAN128> ();
  static {
    for (IDENT_EAN128 ident: IDENT_EAN128.values())
      codeMap.put(ident.getCode(), ident);
  }

  private IDENT_EAN128 (String code) {
   ...
  }

  public static IDENT_EAN128 search (String code) {
    return codeMap.get(code);
  }

  public abstract Parser[] getParsers ();
}
```

Comment: Glad you found something you are comfortable with.  Feel free to "accept" an answer if you want by clicking the check mark next to the answer.  (You can even accept your own if you want.)  If you have enough reputation, you can also upvote any answers that contributed meaningfully to the conversation.